# Module not specified when exporting .aar to Unity3d

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

Recently, I tried to export aar package to unity using Android Studio. I've done the following tips.

1. import the classes.jar from unity.
2. modify MainActivity extends from UnityPlayerActivity.
3. modify build.gradle.
4. modify AndroidManifest.xml.
5. delete useless file.

Here, I got a problem.

When I modify 'com.android.application' into 'com.android.library' in build.gradle, the app module is no longer useful. And I cannot build apk so that I can't export aar package.
[Error: Module not specified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOCnE.png)

This is kind of annoying. Would anyone please help me with it? Thanks!

Comment: do you have `settings.gradle` and `app.iml`? if yes then can you please post the code here?

Comment: Of course I have, they are generated by Android Studio.
settings.gradle `code` include ':app' `code`and app.iml have a lot of code.